# Reload perticular textbox/select option using javaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to refresh/reload a particular textbox/ Select option using javaScript. Just like when the page loads for the first time.

There is a option of location.reload() but it reloads the whole page which is not an option.

I want to perform some action. somewhat like

```html
<input type="text" id="1" />
<select id="2">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("1").reload();
document.getElementById("2").reload();
```

How do I do this??

I would want to reload just the textbox or select option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set it empty space.

```
document.getElementById("1").value =""
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=""
```

Check code answering using mobile.

Comment: Thanks, Just added -----  document.getElementById("1").value ="Select"

Answer (score 1):

Just put everything inside a form and add a reset input type button.

```html
<form action="/">
<input type="text" id="1" />
<select id="2">
<option></option>
</select>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, this code ill take a note it will definately help me in the future :)